# How to query a CR for a given namespace using client-go RESTClient() function

Tags: kubernetes, client-go, kubernetes-custom-resources

This golang code works well:

```
    topics := &kafka.KafkaTopicList{}
    d, err := clientSet.RESTClient().Get().AbsPath("/apis/kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2/kafkatopics").DoRaw(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
```

However I'd like to get the `kafkatopics` custom resources only for a given namespace, is there a way to do this using `client-go` api? For information, using `clientSet.RESTClient().Get().Namespace("<my-namespace>")` returns the following error message: "the server could not find the requested resource"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```golang
group := "kafka.strimzi.io"
version := "v1beta2"
plural := "kafkatopics"

namespace := "..."

d, err := clientSet.RESTClient().Get().AbsPath(
    fmt.Sprintf("/apis/%s/%s/namespaces/%s/%s",
        group,
        version,
        namespace,
        plural,
    ).DoRaw(context.TODO())
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

I think using CRDs, `client-go`'s [`Namespace`](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.28.0/rest#Request.Namespace) method incorrectly appends `namespace/{namespace}` into the request URL with CRDs.

You want:

```
/apis/{group}/{version}/namespaces/{namespace}/{plural}
```

Using `Namespace`, you get:

```
/apis/{group}/{version}/{plural}/namespaces/{namespace}
```

You can prove this to yourself with:

```golang
log.Println(restClient.Get().Namespace(namespace).AbsPath(
    fmt.Sprintf("/apis/%s/%s/%s",
        group,
        version,
        plural,
    ),
).URL().String())
```

Comment: You're welcome! Pleased it helps